# "here we go" or "here you go" when food is served in a restaurant

Tags: sentence-meaning

In a US restaurant, a waiter said "here XXX go." as he put the plate on the table.

As he said it very fast, I can't distinct whether it's "here we go" or "here you go".

So, what's the waiter supposed to say in that case?

I supposed it meant that the food was ready to eat, but I am not quite sure if any other possible implications of this sentence in this scenario?

I browsed many websites and along with the questions regarding "here we go" and "here you go" in this SE as well, and it seems to me "here you go" is correct, but still not sure whether "here we go" is applicable in this context.

Comment: I think most wait staff would say, "Here **you** go" in such settings, but these are such informal constructs that I don't think I could deem "Here we go" as `not applicable` or `inappropriate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @J.R. writes, it could really be either ***here you go*** or ***here we go***. There's no correct answer. I agree that ***here you go*** is more likely. But consider the following possibilities:

If you were eating by yourself, the waiter almost certainly said ***here you go***, unless the waiter planned to eat with you! One exception might be is if both you and the waiter had to wait a while for the plate to be prepared, in which case ***here we go*** could have been referring to the readiness of the food, which essentially affected both of you.

If you were eating with a group of people and you were all waiting patiently -- and if the waiter brought ought more than one plate at once -- ***here we go*** could have been preferable.

This is probably true for any language, not just English. The waiter could have been very personable (perhaps wanting a good tip) and just wanted to seem like one of your party by saying "we" instead of "you." This is typical in lots of scenarios outside of food service. For example, anyone who represents you, such as a real estate agent or a lawyer, may refer to you as "we" in the spirit of showing that their happiness is tied intrinsically to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Either would be natural, with **we** or **you**.

In context, both of those fixed phrases mean "Here's what you want".

**we** can actually be used as a form of address. *And how are we today?* can mean "How are *you* today?" The  pronoun **we** there expresses solicitude.

A customer walking into a shop he visits regularly might be asked by the proprietor:

> And how are we today?

If a child is taken to the emergency room with a cut on her knee, the doctor might ask the family or the child:

> And what were we doing?

and mean thereby, "Can you tell me how it happened?"

A waiter or waitress might come over to a table, where the diners have been looking at their menus for a while, and ask:

> Have we decided?